# How to understand the underlying pointer address of a smart pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

I'm taking Udacity's C++ Nanodegree and there is something in the lecture about smart pointers, which I believe to be a mistake, or I'm missing something.
Consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

class MyClass
{
private:
    std::string _text;

public:
    MyClass() {}
    MyClass(std::string text) { _text = text; }
    ~MyClass() { std::cout << _text << " destroyed" << std::endl; }
    void setText(std::string text) { _text = text; }
};

int main()
{
    // create unique pointer to proprietary class
    std::unique_ptr<MyClass> myClass1(new MyClass());
    std::unique_ptr<MyClass> myClass2(new MyClass("String 2"));

    // call member function using ->
    myClass1->setText("String 1");

    // use the dereference operator * 
    *myClass1 = *myClass2;

    ---This is the part I don't understand---
    // use the .get() function to retrieve a raw pointer to the object
    std::cout << "Objects have stack addresses " << myClass1.get() << " and " << myClass2.get() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I understand this example this way:
They use the [unique_ptr's get method](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get) to get a pointer that points to the managed data, which is allocated on the heap. So this address should be a heap address, and **not** the stack address where the internal pointer lives. (The stack address of the smart pointer's internal raw pointer shouldn't be accessible from the outside?)

The official explanation to this code says: "Obviously, both pointers have different addresses on the stack, even after copying the contents from myClass2 to  myClass1."

But shouldn't it say something like: "Both pointers still point to their respective heap addresses, only the data has been copied from one address to the other"?

Comment: Yes, `.get()` does not return a stack address (unless you did something really funky).

Comment: `myClass1.get()` is not a stack address of anything. I'm not sure why they mention stack addresses at all. They are hardly relevant.

Comment: that's what surprised me. so the text in cout doesn't make sense either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct. The `unique_ptr` *objects* have different stack addresses, and they point to distinct heap addresses as well.

Doing something like `myClass1.reset(myClass2.get())` would make both `unique_ptr` objects point to the same heap address, a terrible violation of the `unique_ptr` invariant.